# Delete Record but retain sequence Number in Database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have  table with following fields

```
VouhcerID, VoucherNumber, VoucherDate, etc...
```

Now the situation is when some voucher get rejected. I don't need to retain the record in database but the sequence number should be retained in database. Say I have Following record in database with sequence number `JV001, JV002, JV003` Now if `JV003` get rejected. Its record from database should be rejected but when new record is inserted it should get `JV004` as `VoucherNumber`. One option is to add a Boolean field in database named `isdeleted` and make it `true` when record get rejected.  Any other suggession

Comment: Lets say when JV003 is rejected,then what you want to do with the other field values?you want to remove them from a table and just keep sequence no with rest of the fields as null or you just want to delete the whole row from a table and whenever new row is inserted get the sequence no as JV004?

Comment: Ideally I want to completely remove the row from database. Keeping all other fields as null may not be feasible as I have to allow all other field to take null value

Answer (score 1):

I think you option sounds good.

Another option is separate column in to two columns

**column 1 :** contains the non integer part of the column (ie, JV in the above example) 
**Column 2 :** contains the number part and you can make it as an **int identity** column, which will maintain the sequence number.

And you have to combine the two columns for the ID column

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a "Computed Column". Ex: ('JV'+CONVERT(nvarchar,[Rec_ID],(0)))

Comment: Voucher numbers is reset at closing of year

Comment: I think the auto-increment column can be reset when the year is reset using query “DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)”.

Answer (score 0):

Alter table to add identity column and whenver there is new insert,just insert like this:

```
 alter table yourtable add id int identity(1,1)
    INSERT INTO yourtable(VouhcerID,...)
    select 'JV'+CASE WHEN len(cast(id as varchar)=1 then '00'+cast(id as varchar) else  CASE WHEN len(cast(id as varchar)=2 then '0'+cast(id as varchar) else cast(id as varchar) end end,... from table
```